# Pull Data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to scrape data from Yahoo Finance into a Google Sheet.

More specifically, this page:

`https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics/`

From this page, I'm trying to scrape the value for "Price/Book (mrq)".

So far I've created a Google Sheet, opened Apps Scripts and have the following code:

```
function yahooF() {
  const ticker = 'AAPL';
  const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics/`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  const contentText = res.getContentText();
  const Price/Book = contentText.match(/<fin-streamer(?:.*?)active="">(\d+[,]?[\d\.]+?)<\/fin-streamer>/);
  console.log(Price/Book[1]);
  return Price/Book[1];
}
```

I'm unable to pull the data, any ideas where I may be going wrong?

I'm hoping the resolution will also teach me how to pull other numbers from that sheet.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:python]? Please don't tag spam.

Comment: Hi Chris
My apologies, I lack programming knowledge and genuinely thought it was python.